# Loading project from a mapped drive

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm on a Windows machine loading an IntelliJ Idea project from a mapped drive connected to a Samba share on a remote Unix VM.

First of all, I know loading a project from a mapped drive is generally discouraged (and for good reason), but it's unavoidable for me on this client.

The project loads fine (albeit understandable slow), but then once the project loads, the IDE comes to a halt. I can't perform any actions at this point, including opening the options menu to look for a remedy.

I'm guessing that Idea does some sort of file indexing that is locking up the IDE since it has to index over the network. Is there a way to disable indexing/whatever is causing this, or is this approach a lost cause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured out a solution. Idea is now running smooth as butter!

Browse to File --> Settings. Click the "general" section, then uncheck "Synchronize files on frame activation".